# How do I treat two identical characters separately?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the 3rd level of python-challenges(http://www.pythonchallenge.com/index.php)

I have written some code to solve the challenge.

```
    text = "EXAcTLYdsgsdcTLY"
    jlist = []
    boo = False

    for i in text:
        if ord(i) in range(97, 123) and text.index(i) in range(3, len(text) - 2):
            j0 = text.index(i)
            j1 = text[j0 + 1]
            j2 = text[j0 + 2]
            j3 = text[j0 + 3]
            j_1 = text[j0 - 1]
            j_2 = text[j0 - 2]
            j_3 = text[j0 - 3]

            jlist = [j_3, j_2, j_1, j1, j2, j3]

            boo = False

        for j in jlist:
            if ord(j) in range(65, 91):
                boo = True
            else:
                boo = False
                break

        if boo == True:
            print(i)
```

Now the problem is that there are two 'c's in the code. The same jlist that is produced for the first c is reproduced for the second c instead of creating a new jlist for it.

[The code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hsJL.jpg)

Comment: 1. What is the question that you are solving here? 2. Your output is **not an image**. Please copy plain text output into your post.

Comment: `if boo == True`? Why not `if (boo == True) == True`?

Comment: @melpomene they are exactly the same, both return the same value

Comment: @Zeus3101 Yes, that's the point. They're also both unnecessarily complicated. Just as you can remove `== True` from `(boo == True) == True` without changing the meaning, you can also remove `== True` from `boo == True` without changing the meaning. Why not `if boo: print(i)` if `boo` is already a boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `index` returns the first occurrence of the character, and so this assignment will give the wrong value for the second `c`:

```
        j0 = text.index(i)
```

Instead, get the position in the `for` statement, using `enumerate()`:

```
for j0, i in enumerate(text):
    if ord(i) in range(97, 123) and text.index(i) in range(3, len(text) - 2):
        # no need to calculate j0 now.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was wondering if index() actually considered the first occurence. This fixed it.